# Browser.CloseAsync() for Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin app that opens a external Url using the following code:

```
 public async Task OpenBrowser(Uri uri)
        {
            await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, new BrowserLaunchOptions
            {
                LaunchMode = BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred,
                TitleMode = BrowserTitleMode.Hide               
            });

            
        }


await OpenBrowser(new Uri(response.LandingPageUrl));
```

I'm looking for a function that Closes a Browser after X seconds it has been opened by it, but I didn't find any examples or information in the original documentation that might help me solving this problem.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Close(); does not exist in xamarin, do I have to install something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such function like `Close()` to close a Browser after X seconds.

And I don't think you can close the browser programmatically. Only user can tap the close button to close it.

Comment: I chose to open my Url in a WebView instead. This way I could use PopAsync to return to my main page after X time.